# React to mouse-click event on image at certain coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

let's assume we have an image:

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg">
```

Now I need an event handler which is activated when the user clicks on this image on a certain coordinate(-range).

Example:
[image]

Whenever the user clicks somewhere in the red circle, an event should be fired. I'm happy about every idea / hint / solution.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code using picture you provided. Check this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="image.jpg" width="400" height="300" alt="" id="myImgId" />
    <p>X:<span id="x"></span></p>
    <p>Y:<span id="y"></span></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
        myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;

        function FindPosition(oElement)
        {
            if(typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined")
            {
                for(var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent)
                {
                    posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
                    posY += oElement.offsetTop;
                }
                return [ posX, posY ];
            }
            else
            {
                return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
            }
        }

        function GetCoordinates(e)
        {
            var PosX = 0;
            var PosY = 0;
            var ImgPos;
            ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
            if (!e) var e = window.event;
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
            {
                PosX = e.pageX;
                PosY = e.pageY;
            }
            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
            {
                PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                    + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                    + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }
            PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
            PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];

            if(PosX > 125 && PosX < 143 && PosY > 195 && PosY < 221) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            } else if(PosX > 16 && PosX < 25 && PosY > 141 && PosY < 152) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            } else if(PosX > 99 && PosX < 117 && PosY > 40 && PosY < 62) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            } else if(PosX > 284 && PosX < 301 && PosY > 64 && PosY < 92) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            } else if(PosX > 264 && PosX < 285 && PosY > 138 && PosY < 167) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            } else if(PosX > 345 && PosX < 359 && PosY > 203 && PosY < 230) {
                alert("You clicked on the red circle");
            }

            document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
            document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't seem to be working if the img width / height is removed..